# Послу установки php 7 конфликт php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686

Tags: php7

Послу установки php 7 конфликт php70w-common conflicts with php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686.

Пробовал удалить

```
 `yum erase php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686`

yum remove php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686
```

Выдает Пакет(ы) php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686 доступны, но не установлены.
Нет пакетов, отмеченных для удаления
`yum search php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686` - совпадений для php-common-5.6.31-1.el6.remi.i686 не найдено

`yum list installed` не находит php-common-5.6

```
`rpm -qa | grep php`   выводит php70w-common-7.0.23-2.w6.i386, т.е. php-common-5.6
```

не видит.

Comment: Я сносил 5.6 целиком перед установкой семёрки

Comment: именно так и поступил, полностью снес предыщующую версию php